# How to create an array of IloModel and IloObjective object pointers in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, cplex, rational-team-concert

I am coding a decomposition algorithm including scenario subproblems. I need to use model pointer to create subproblem optimization models. Then, it is needed to modify the objective function coefficient of each subproblem as the algorithm proceeds. I need to use pointers to avoid creating the subproblem models every time from scratch. How should I do that? Can I use this:

```
 IloModel** MaxProblemPtr= new(env) IloModel*[numberOfScenarios];

 IloObjective** MaxObjPtr= new(env) IloObjective*[numberOfScenarios];
```

Then, is it correct to keep pointers to the implementation instances for each scenario subproblem like the followings:

```
IloModel MaxProblem(env);
*(MaxProblemPtr[scnenarioN])=MaxProblem.getImpl();

IloObjective MaxObj=IloAdd(MaxProblem, IloMaximize(env));
*(MaxObjPtr[scnenarioN])=MaxObj.getImpl();
```

Thank you much,

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) to hold a collection of pointers. It's much easier to use and understand. e.g:

```
std::vector<IloModel*> models(numberOfScenarios);
```

Then you can fill it like so:

```
models.push_back(new IloModel);
```